Scroll not working when rendering ReactNativeZomableView inside FlatList
I am rendering ReactNativeZomableView inside FaltList but scroll event on FlatList is not working on IOS.
Code example:
<FlatList
   ...
   renderItem={(item, index) => {
      return (
       <ReactNativeZomableView ...>
          <FastImage .../>
       </ReactNativeZomableView>
      )
   }}
/>

When I remove ReactNativeZomableView component, scroll is working fine.
FastImage - "react-native-fast-image"
ReactNativeZoomableView - "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view"


How is the zoomable view supposed to know whether you want to zoom it or scroll the FlatList? If you add space around the ZoomableView, and drag on that space, does the FlatList work?

Hey Abe, sorry for late reply. I wanted it like zoomable view should take control only if the view is zoomed in else swipe should be handled by FlatList. Thanks
